# Tversky Loss function for RGB masks

Tags: loss-functions, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I have a very imbalanced dataset for my semantic segmentation problem (monitoring deforestation using setellite images) and I found **Tversky Loss** to be much better than **categorical crossentropy** (due to dataset imbalance). My problem is that the masks for my images are in RGB. Here's an example of an image and a matching mask:

[image]

If I understand correctly, our masks should have the following form: **H x W x Num_classes**. In my case, I have **3 classes**(*forest - green, deforestation - red, other - blue*) and the masks are 512 x 512 x 3, but instead of pixel values like this [1; 0; 0], [0; 1; 0], [0; 0; 1] I have [226,19,15] (*red*), [11,195,72] (*green*), [51, 15, 200] (*blue*). And categorical cross-entropy works with it, but I want to try Tversky Loss and with such masks it is impossible. It looks like a one-hot encoding issue to me, but I'm not sure.

Here is an example of **code for my Tversky Loss** (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9395 taken from here):

```
ALPHA = 0.5
BETA = 0.5
# First example
def TverskyLoss(targets, inputs, alpha=ALPHA, beta=BETA, smooth=1e-6):
    #flatten label and prediction tensors
    inputs = tf.squeeze(inputs)
    targets = tf.squeeze(targets)
        
    #True Positives, False Positives & False Negatives
    TP = tf.reduce_sum((inputs * targets))
    FP = tf.reduce_sum(((1-targets) * inputs))
    FN = tf.reduce_sum((targets * (1-inputs)))
       
    Tversky = (TP + smooth) / (TP + alpha*FP + beta*FN + smooth)  
        
    return 1 - Tversky
# Second example
def tversky_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    alpha = 0.5
    beta  = 0.5
    
    ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(y_true))
    p0 = y_pred      # proba that voxels are class i
    p1 = ones - y_pred # proba that voxels are not class i
    g0 = y_true
    g1 = ones - y_true
    
    num = tf.math.reduce_sum(p0 * g0, (0,1,2))
    den = num + alpha*tf.math.reduce_sum(p0*g1,(0,1,2)) + beta*tf.math.reduce_sum(p1*g0,(0,1,2))
    
    T = tf.math.reduce_sum(num/den) # when summing over classes, T has dynamic range [0 Ncl]
    
    Ncl = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[-1], 'float32')
    return Ncl-T
```

Here is an example of predicting a model while training using Tversky Loss. Obviously the loss function doesn't work:
[image]

I am using standard **U-net architecture**, with this output layer (3 filters for 3 output classes). Looks like I should change activation to "sigmoid" if I'll convert my masks:

```
conv = Conv2D(3, 1, padding='same', activation='softmax')(conv_prev)
```

What should I do to use my Tversky Loss, convert each mask to values like [1; 0; 0] and to see my results do the inverse conversion to RGB colors like this [226,19,15]? Is it possible to do such transformations using **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator**? And what if I had 5 or 10 classes, how to view results of output tensor with shape **H x W x 10** ? I tried to figure out this problem myself and in this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) the masks also had 3 classes. Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding this preprocessing function to my **ImageDataGenerator** I solved the problem with masks stored in RGB. My classes don't have a common red value, so I decided to use it to separate the classes:

```
def preprocess_one_hot_encode(image_rgb):
    img = np.copy(image_rgb[..., 0])
    for i, num in enumerate([11, 226, 51]):
        img[img == num] = i
    one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(img, 3)
    return one_hot
```

After that I set the same **random seed** for the generators, and most importantly, I set a much lower **learning rate** for my **Adam optimizer**. Due to a very imbalanced dataset, my model only learned from the most common class. After these changes, I found that all loss functions were correct and the **learning rate** was a real issue.